# Matlab fmincon - No feasible solution found, but no error caught

Tags: matlab, optimization, error-handling

I'm using the optimisation function "fmincon" and in some case it doesn't converge. I must identify these cases and take the necessary actions, but all the methods used fails in catching the errors, so that I continue to get the error:

```
No feasible solution found.

fmincon stopped because the size of the current search direction is less than
twice the default value of the step size tolerance but constraints are not 
satisfied to within the selected value of the constraint tolerance.
```

First, I tried selecting the exitflag of the function: if it returns a known error (-1, 1, 0...), but each time I had the error, the exitflag returned had a correct value.

```
[x,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(@(x) costFunction(x,INPUTS),x0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
if exitflag == 0
    do something;
end
```

I then tried with the "try/catch" structure, but also in this case, the code continued to run and no error was cought...

```
try %start try/catch
    [x,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(@(x) costFunction(x,INPUTS),x0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
catch err
   disp(err.identifier);
       ... actions 
end  % end try/catch
```

Any suggestion is kindly welcomed.

ps: the options used are:

```
options = optimset(oldopts,'Display','notify', 'Algorithm','active-set', 'MaxFunEvals', 10000);
```

Comment: Did you supply an `x0` that satisfies the constraints?

Comment: I checked, actually in some case the x0 doesn't satisfy the constraints, I will update also this.

Answer (score 0):

1. what is in `oldopts`?
2. `is less than twice the default value of the step size tolerance` suggests you need to either change the step size or the tolerance values. There are several ways you can go about that: guess or show the iterative display.

   ```
   optimset(oldopts,'Display','iter' ...% or 'iter-detailed'
   ```
3. Once you figure out what you want to change, you can set it with:

   ```
   optimset(options,'stepsize', 1e-2) % or optimset(options,'tolX', 1e-e)...
   ```
4. Stop looking at exit flag to throw an error. The error is a convergence or iteration problem.
5. Ask yourself if the algorithm can able to converge using graphical methods (if possible)
6. RTM: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-fails.html

Comment: ok, this is also an option and I will try, but still, it should catch the error, not passing over like nothing...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) you should be looking out for `exitFlag == -2` and not `0` to check for that scenario:

i.e.

```
[x,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(@(x) costFunction(x,INPUTS),x0,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
if exitflag == -2
    %// Handle non-convergence
else
    %// Converged
end
```